# Find textbox with the largest number

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie to JavaScript. I have a series of textboxes and a button on my page. When the button is pressed I want to find which number is the largest, and add a border around that textbox.

Currently when I click the button there is no change, and I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

document.getElementById("findMax").addEventListener("click", function(){

var num1 = document.getElementById('number1').value
var num2 = document.getElementById('number2').value
var num3 = document.getElementById('number3').value
var num4 = document.getElementById('number4').value
var num5 = document.getElementById('number5').value

// Find the largest of the nums
if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3) && (num1 > num4) && (num1 > num5){
document.getElementById("number1").style.borderColor="#008000"
}
else if((num2> num1) && (num2> num3) && (num2> num4) && (num2> num5)){
document.getElementById("number2").style.borderColor="#008000"
}
else if((num3> num1) && (num3> num2) && (num3> num4) && (num3> num5)){
document.getElementById("number3").style.borderColor="#008000"
}
else if((num4> num1) && (num4> num2) && (num4> num3) && (num4> num5)){
document.getElementById("number4").style.borderColor="#008000"
}
else if((num5> num1) && (num5> num2) && (num5> num3) && (num5> num4)){
document.getElementById("number4").style.borderColor="#008000"
}
else{
// ERROR: No Largest Num!
}});

    </script>
    <style>
      input[type='text'] {width:50px;}
      textarea {width:500px;height:300px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>
    <input type="text" id="number1" />
    <input type="text" id="number2" />
    <input type="text" id="number3" />
    <input type="text" id="number4" />
    <input type="text" id="number5" />
    </p>
    <button id="findMax">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is jQuery allowed in the answer?

Comment: @Wowsk op didn't tag jquery.

Comment: Try to use console to debug. You are missing a `)` in your first if condition `if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3) && (num1 > num4) && (num1 > num5){` to `if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3) && (num1 > num4) && (num1 > num5)){`

Comment: Move your `script` to the end of your file, or use document ready.  It can't see `findMax` where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function, here is the working template

```js
document.getElementById("findMax").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1').value) || 0;
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number2').value) || 0;
  var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number3').value) || 0;
  var num4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number4').value) || 0;
  var num5 = parseInt(document.getElementById('number5').value) || 0;

  var max = Math.max(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);

  document.getElementById("number1").style.borderColor = (max == num1) ? "#008000" : "inherit";
  document.getElementById("number2").style.borderColor = (max == num2) ? "#008000" : "inherit";
  document.getElementById("number3").style.borderColor = (max == num3) ? "#008000" : "inherit";
  document.getElementById("number4").style.borderColor = (max == num4) ? "#008000" : "inherit";
  document.getElementById("number5").style.borderColor = (max == num5) ? "#008000" : "inherit";
});
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  width: 50px;
}
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="number1" />
    <input type="text" id="number2" />
    <input type="text" id="number3" />
    <input type="text" id="number4" />
    <input type="text" id="number5" />
  </p>
  <button id="findMax">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var maxNum = -Infinity,
    maxDom = null;

for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var dom = document.getElementById('number' + i),
        num = parseInt(dom.value);

    if(!isNaN(num) && num > maxNum) {
        maxNum = num;
        maxDom = dom;
    }
}

if(maxDom) {
    maxDom.style.borderColor = '#008000';
}
```